# How to set up Spark cluster on Windows machines?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, mesos

I am trying to set up a Spark cluster on Windows machines.
The way to go here is using the Standalone mode, right?
What are the concrete disadvantages of not using Mesos or YARN?  And how much pain would it be to use either one of those? Does anyone have some experience here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, I got an answer in the user-group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spark-users/SyBJhQXBqIs

The standalone mode is indeed the way to go. Mesos does not work under Windows and YARN probably neither.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note, YARN should eventually work on Windows via the Hortonworks Data Platform (version 2.0 beta is on YARN but it is on Linux only at this time).  Another potential route is to have it work against Hadoop 1.1 (Hortonworks Data Platform for Windows 1.1) - but your approach of having it run on Standalone mode is definitely the easiest to getting of the ground.