# Can't start Apache Spark on Windows using Cygwin

Tags: apache-spark

I am sorry if this is too trivial but I am very new to Spark. I built Apache Spark on Windows from code using Maven. I used Cygwin to build and it worked fine. Now I am unable to start it using the command (./start-master.sh) from the sbin directory.

I get the below error :
failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
full log in /cygdrive/c/Spark/spark-1.5.1/sbin/../logs/spark-auser-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1.host
```

I understand it is looking for the spark-launcher_2.10-1.5.1.jar in the classpath but I am not able to identify in the scripts where is it defining the classpath or the lib directory.

Comment: Are you using JDK/JRE from cygwin?

Comment: @kostya : Spark would run inside the JVM. I am able to access the JRE from cygwin too. I am running Java 1.7.

Comment: "I used Cygwin to build and it worked fine" - you mean the build produces no errors, but what you are proving to yourself here is that it is in fact not fine, yet. How exactly do you do the build? Which documentation did you follow?

Comment: Just an FYI, you can also start a Spark Cluster on Windows itself (e.g. spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master ++ spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://localhost:7077)

Comment: @Gimby : i ran the following command  build/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn  -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package. I used the URL http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html

Comment: @geek so the steps for "building a runnable distribution" were skipped then?

Comment: @Gimby : I didnt do those steps. Do I need them ? It is mentioned that the  Apache launcher is enough. I will try those steps as well.

Comment: @Gimby : I completed those steps and they completed successfully but I still can't run start-master.sh file.

Comment: @PatrickMcGloin : I think that the command you mentioned is not correct.

Comment: That was supposed to be two commands, the ++ meaning a newline. They should work.

Comment: Ok. I built a runnable distribution that created a new Custom-spark tar file in the parent directory. I took this file Untarred it in a different directory went to the bin subdirectory and am able to bring up the scala-shell. It is late here will get some sleep hope it will work tomorrow. Thanks to all.

Comment: Can someone who participated in the comment-based conversation above please summarize in an Answer? thx.

Comment: @shoover since it is 1st of June, I decided to wrap this up. Hope that's OK! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could follow the [Building a Runnable Distribution](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-a-runnable-distribution) steps as Gimby mentioned, like this for example:

```
./make-distribution.sh --name custom-spark --tgz -Psparkr -Phadoop-2.4 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Pyarn
```

---

As Patrick McGloin mentioned, you could also start a Spark Cluster on Windows itself, like this for example:

```
spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://localhost:7077
```

You can read more in [Spark Standalone Mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) and [How to set up Spark cluster on Windows machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465581/how-to-set-up-spark-cluster-on-windows-machines)

---

Finally as OP mentioned, (s)he was able to built a runnable distribution that created a new Custom-spark tar file in the parent directory. (S)he took this file, untarred it in a different directory, went to the bin subdirectory and then was able to bring up the scala-shell.